# Performing one-way repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I have a dataset as follows:

There are several patients, for each patient is measured how much sleep he/she has had the previous night, in seconds, and how many seizures he/she has had this night.

```
patient    sleepPreviousDay    seizures
 0132           37979             0
 0132           48204             2
 0132           35626             1
 0132           56612             4
 0133           66799             2
 0133           32899             0
 0133           34295             1
```

I'd like to test if there is a correlation between the amount of sleep in the previous night and the amount of seizures during the current night. I plan on doing this using an one-way repeated measures ANOVA, correct me if this is an incorrect statistical analysis for this problem.

I have little experience using R and even less in statistics and would hope if someone could tell me if this is the correct way of doing the analysis in R:

```
//Take factors
df$patient <- as.factor(df$patient)
df$sleepPreviousDay <- as.factor(df$sleepPreviousDay)

// Run analysis
anova < aov(seizures ~ sleepPreviousDay + Error(patient/sleepPreviousDay), data=df)
summary(anova)
```

Also, if I were to add a sex and age column to the table, since both affect the amount of sleep a person needs, would I then simple have to change the `Error` to `Error(patient/(sex+age)/sleepPreviousDay)` and would this even have a real effect since sex and age would always be the same within a patient?

Answer (score 1):

First, questions about coding are off topic here.

Second, repeated measures ANOVA makes assumptions about the data that are nearly always unreasonable (chiefly, the assumption of sphericity). Multilevel models are usually more reasonable.

Third, in your particular case, your dependent variable is a count, so ANOVA is probably not a good fit. You want a count regression model.

So, you probably want a nonlinear multilevel model.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Would that be something like 'Repeated measures logistic regression'?